# config.duration not getting applied in Canary release plugin of KONG

Tags: kong, canary-deployment, kong-plugin

I am trying to configure Canary release plugin in Kong.

The plugin get activated on epoch time provided in **config.start** parameter. But the **config.duration** provided in seconds does not work, and the requests keep on getting routed to the upstream service.

Sample configuration::
{ "steps": null, "upstream_port": , "upstream_uri": "/test-uri", "upstream_fallback": false, "start": 1582109400, "groups": null, "percentage": null, "duration": 60, "hash": "none", "upstream_host": "" }

I have configured this plugin on a service. Running Kong V1.3

Any pointers will be helpful.